# Use jQuery to wrap all elements in a div

Tags: jquery

I have quite a strange markup but nevertheless, i have 3 divs:

```
<div id="div1"></div>

<div id="div4"></div>

<div id="div12"></div>
```

There may be other elements in between these 3 divs but what i need to do is make sure that there is a div wrapping these 3 divs so the markup will end up like this:

```
<div class="wrapped">
    <div id="div1"></div>

    <div id="div4"></div>

    <div id="div12"></div>
</div>
```

Is this possible using jQuery's wrap or wrapAll functions?

Comment: Should all other elements between the 3 divs also should be wrapped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's possible with [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/). You can use [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/), [andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) and [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to match the elements between `#div1` and `#div12`, inclusive:

```
$("#div1").nextUntil("#div12").andSelf().add("#div12")
          .wrapAll("<div class='wrapped'></div>");
```

Comment: This does not work if there is any plain text in between the divs, see my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/alp82/PZvEd/

Comment: @Alp, good point. Questioner, would this be a problem in your case?

Comment: Hmmm, actually the wrapping doesnt work, it only takes one element into its wrap

Comment: @ben, strange, it works for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mzWq/). Which browser are you using?

Comment: To fix the plain text issue, you can wrap any text nodes before running the code in the answer above. See http://jsfiddle.net/PZvEd/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
var wrapper = $('<div></div>').addClass('wrapped');
var parent = $('#div1').parent();
wrapper.append($('#div1, #div4, #div12')).appendTo(parent);
```

You can get rid of the wrapper var if you prefer. Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DHTd6/

Comment: Did you link to the correct Fiddle?

Comment: @jensgram heh. no I didn't. That fiddle was for a different question. Thanks for pointing that out.