# wrap all elements with div

Tags: jquery, html, wrapall

I have been all over this site but have not found my answer. I am trying to wrap all divs into one wrapper. All I have been able to do so far using wrapAll is to add a container around each div. I don't want to do that. I have this

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="panel-cell">Content</div>
     <div class="panel-cell">Content</div>
     <div class="panel-cell">Content</div>
     <div class="panel-cell">Content</div>
 </div><!--END container-fluid-->
```

I need to turn it into this

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="panel-cell">Content</div>
         <div class="panel-cell">Content</div>
         <div class="panel-cell">Content</div>
         <div class="panel-cell">Content</div>
     </div><!--END container-->
 </div><!--END container-fluid-->
```

Is this possible to do with Jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to wrap all elements in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856648/use-jquery-to-wrap-all-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. If you read what I am trying to do, it's different than the other post. He is trying to separate divs. I want them all wrapped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/woLzgvok/

```js
$(".panel-cell").wrapAll("<div class='container'></div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="panel-cell">Content</div>
     <div class="panel-cell">Content</div>
     <div class="panel-cell">Content</div>
     <div class="panel-cell">Content</div>
 </div><!--END container-fluid-->
```

[WrapAll Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

Answer (score 2):

.wrapAll API in jquery does this

```
$(".panel-cell").wrapAll("<div class='container'></div>");
```

Comment: It is working but not how it's intended. I am using wordpress with a page builder. When I try this code, it takes every single element on the page and wraps it into the same div. So, I guess maybe it is working the way it's intended. I need to figure out a way to make it work only for the individual rows.

Comment: Give id for the specific container and run

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
var html = $(".container-fluid").html()
var temp = "<div class='container'>"+html+"</div>"
$(".container-fluid").html(temp)
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Well, it did but I can't do it on the container-fluid because it defeats what I am trying to do. I tried to modify your version but got errors.